# How @Transactional working on different transaction manager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have multiple databases, so I created multiple transaction manager to manage their transaction.

I've heared that `@Transactional`'s default propagation level is `Propagation.REQUIRED`.

If propagation level is `REQUIRED`, the child transaction will join to parent transaction.

But if so, the child transaction's transaction manager will became parent transaction manager.

Does it correct? Or does different transaction manager creates their own transaction?

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional( transactionManager = "mainTransactionManager" )
public class MainService {
  
  private final MainDao mainDao;

  private final SubService subService;

  public void doMain() {
     String result = "Fail";
     try {
       mainDao.update(); // Exception on here, mainTransactionManager will rollback
       result = "Success"
     } finally {
       subService.doSub( result ); // Exception on here, mainTransactionManager & subTransactionManager will rollback
     }
  }

}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional( transactionManager = "subTransactionManager" )
public class SubService {
  
  private final SubDao subDao;

  public void doSub( String result ) {
     subDao.update( result );
  }

}
```

Comment: With multiple transaction manager you have multiple transactions, there is no single transaction across those different databases.

Comment: Yes, it would almost behave like `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation across different transaction managers. The `REQUIRED` will only be effective if the inner/sub method calls happens to use the same transaction manager as the parent. Not sure, what would happen if a method using `mainTM` calls a method using `subTM`, which internally calls another method that uses `mainTM`. Would grand-parent method's transaction propagate to its grand-child? The middle will definitely use a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try ChainedTransactionManager: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html

```
@Bean 
PlatformTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager() {
  return new ChainedTransactionManager(mainTransactionManager, subTransactionManager);
}
```

And use it over both methods

Comment: The ```ChainedTransactionManager``` is deprecated. But your answer was helpful because I've found that ```TransactionSynchronization``` can replace it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of your requirements. If you want to keep the transactions in your DBs independent, then you will have to use REQUIRES_NEW. Otherwise, REQUIRED would suffice if you want them to be managed under the same transactional block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).